# Why does using this code generates this error and how to fix it?

Tags: c, cs50

The error I get is

> error: passing float to parameter of incompatible type 'const char *'
> printf(finalprice, "%f\n");

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
float finalprice(float price, float offer){
    float finalprice = (price - offer) / 100;
    printf(finalprice,"%f\n");
}
int main(void)
{
    float price = get_float("Enter price: \n");
    float offer = get_float("Enter discount amount: \n");
    finalprice(price,offer);
}
```

I'm using the cs50.h library to the get_float() function is already predefined

Comment: Read the documentation of `printf` in your learning material. You want this: `printf("%f\n", finalprice);`

Comment: Also , the program design is wrong. You want this: `printf("%f\n", finalprice(price, offer);` in `main` and `return finalprice;` instead of the `printf` in `finalprice`.

Comment: I did that and still get the same error

Comment: no, you didn't, or the code you compile is not the code you edited.

Comment: I added the return statement which I mistakenly forgotten but still get the same error

Comment: [Edit] your question and **add** the new code.

Comment: BTW: the math is just plain silly... Price = $100, Discount = $5... FinalPrice = $0.95!!! At that prince, I'll take three dozen, please!! :-)

Comment: The first argument to `printf` is the format string.  In fact, it *has* to be, since the format string is needed to determine how to extract the subsequent arguments.

Comment: I advise to read the manual page, whenever you don't know a function.
You can use the command line: `man <function>` (on most systems) or just google the command.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of: printf(finalprice,"%f\n");

Try: printf("%f\n",finalprice);

On a side note ... when dealing with floats/doubles:

Instead of:
float finalprice = (price - offer) / 100;
Use:
float finalprice = (price - offer) / 100.0;

The 100.0 stresses a 'real' number formatting, as opposed to an integer, and makes it more obvious to the programmer.

Comment: You can make it with proper formatting

Answer (score -2):

I solved it, I had to redefine the finalprice1 variable inside the main function, don't know why but it worked

[image]

Comment: Better to post code as text rather than a picture.

Comment: "I had to redefine the finalprice1 variable inside the main function" --> No, that was not required.  A proper use of `printf()` was required.

Comment: Turns out that `printf(finalprice,"%f\n");` vs `printf("%f\n", finalprice);` matters a lot.